# Use php variables in Laravel to send mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.1

I mates,I have this code in my Controller:

```
$name       =   Input::get('fname')." " .Input::get('lname');
$message    =   Input::get('message');
$email      =   Input::get('email');
$subject    =   Input::get('subject');
$phone      =   Input::get('phone');
$area       =   \App\Area::find(1)->name;
$ticket =   \App\Area::find(1)->ticket_sent;
Mail::send('help.send', [ 'Mmessage' => $message, 'Mname' => $name, 'Memail' => $email, 'Msubject' => $subject, 'Mphone' =>$phone, 'Marea' => $area, 'Mticket' => $ticket], function ($message)
    {
        $message->from('asd@gmail.com', 'Name');
        $message->to('support@mycompany.it');
        $message->subject('Support');

    });
$macroArea = MacroArea::find(1);
$macroArea->ticket_sent =$ticket+1;
$macroArea->save();
Session::flash('message', 'The message was successfully send. We will get back to you within 2 business days!');
return Redirect::to('helpDesk');
```

It works so good, but I'm trying to  change two rows in:

```
$message->from($email, $name);
$message->subject($subject);
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I don't understand.

Comment: Or consider using Laravel 5.3, the mail sending has been rewritten and is much easier now: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check the code, need to add use after "function ($message)"

```
$name      =   Input::get('fname')." " .Input::get('lname');
$message   =   Input::get('message');
$email     =   Input::get('email');
$subject   =   Input::get('subject');
$phone     =   Input::get('phone');
$area      =   \App\Area::find(1)->name;
$ticket    =   \App\Area::find(1)->ticket_sent;

Mail::send('help.send', [ 'Mmessage' => $message, 'Mname' => $name, 'Memail' => $email, 'Msubject' => $subject, 'Mphone' =>$phone, 'Marea' => $area, 'Mticket' => $ticket], function ($message) use ($email, $name,$subject)
    {
        $message->from($email, $name);
        $message->to('support@mycompany.it');
        $message->subject($subject);
    });
$macroArea = MacroArea::find(1);
$macroArea->ticket_sent =$ticket+1;
$macroArea->save();
Session::flash('message', 'The message was successfully send. We will get back to you within 2 business days!');
return Redirect::to('helpDesk');
```

Comment: if it helps you then please accept my answer @therock24

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`use()` with anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to pass variables:

```
.... function ($message) use ($email, $name) { ....
```